# How can I push my smaller local repo to BitBucket when the repo at BitBucket is over the limit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Basically I didn't notice some large files got committed. My repo is now over the 4 gigs they allow.

On my local machine I've removed the large files from all commits and pruned and now my local repo is at like 1 gig.

When I `push`, even with `--force`, I get the error:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (44445/44445), completed with 154 local objects.
remote: Repository is over the size limit (4 GB) and will not accept further additions.
remote:
remote: Learn how to reduce your repository size: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/xgMvEw.
```

I've looked over their link but I don't understand really what they want me to do.

I would also be ok with delete all the files on BitBucket and just pushing again but I do not want to lose my issues and things like that, so I can't delete the entire project on BitBucket.

Comment: Well... It's in the error message, you need to reduce your repo size before being able to push anything else to it. Git conserves the whole history of files, so even if you're doing a new push with those files removed, they are still in the repo. You'll need to revert the push with those large files. It is all explained there: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/xgMvEw (yes that's the link given by the error message)

Comment: So I've removed the large files in my local repo using BFG and then pruned. Was that not the right way to do it? Am I supposed to be doing these operations on the remote repo directly?

Comment: I think the important step that is missing is that "undoing the last push" documented there. You have to bring your repo down to the permitted size by undoing the push(es) that brought you over the limit, and then you should be able to push the filtered branch you created.

Comment: I tried the steps in there to revert some bad commits and after following those steps now every time I try to do something it says `Repository is in read only mode (over 4 GB size limit).`

Comment: This may well have changed since a thousand years ago, or whenever it was that I learned it, but at that time you had to contact Bitbucket support and get them to unfreeze your repo.

Comment: Yeah looks like I might have to wait for them to reply. Thanks.

Comment: So they increased my limit and that allowed me to push but at BitBucket it only went down by a little. My local repo is a little over 1 gig, BitBucket still claims slightly over 4 gigs (it was over 5 before my last push).

Comment: I think they need to gc on their end because I cloned my repo again and it is around 1 gig.